Weird subprocess.Popen pipe issue
I am coding a Turkish AI assistant. In order to chat with the language model, I load the language model into the AI. The voice questions I ask are converted to text and entered as input, and the output is read aloud. Unfortunately, the above code snippet does not work as I want. Normally, I need to be able to send input from stdin and read output from stdout interactively using the subprocess.Popen pipe method. But this does not work.
I want to do this interactively.
If I run the following code, I can make chats without any problems via the terminal with the llama model:
process = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "llama-cli", "-m", MODEL_FILE_PATH,
        "-i", "-cnv", "-p", "new session", "--color", "--temp", "0.5",
        "--no-context-shift", "--no-warmup", "-n", "80"
    ],
    # stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    # stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True,
    bufsize=1
)

But if I uncomment #stdout=subprocess.PIPE, the model does not load and hangs.
If uncomment #stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
the model is loaded but it keeps giving irrelevant output, as if input is being provided continuously and process  can not be killed by ctrl+x, it continues to run even if I close the terminal. I had to run
 killall llama-cli.

Would you please guide  me?
EDIT1: The code below somehow ensures that the model is loaded. However, since it cannot detect when the model is loaded, the interactive chat fails. It is delayed. The results can only be seen after pressing enter a few times.
# Start the llama model
process = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "llama-cli", "-m", MODEL_FILE_PATH,
        "-i", "-cnv", "-p", "new session", "--color", "--temp", "0.5",
        "--no-context-shift", "--no-warmup", "-n", "80"
    ],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True,
    bufsize=1,
    universal_newlines=True
)

# Wait for a fixed amount of time for the model to load (e.g., 10 seconds)
print("Waiting for the model to load...")
time.sleep(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds (adjust this value based on your model's load time)
print("Model should be ready!")

# Now start the interactive input-output loop
while True:
    user_input = input("You: ").strip()
    if user_input:
        process.stdin.write(user_input + "\n")
        process.stdin.flush()

    # Read output from the model
    output = process.stdout.readline().strip()
    if output:
        print(f"Model Output: {output}")


You are probably looking for subprocess.run which will run the process, wait, and retrieve back its result.
If you do want to run the subprocess in parallel with your Python program, you need to respond to it when it wants to read or write something to the subprocess.PIPEs. There are many existing questions about this; perhaps start by reviewing the FAQs in the Stack Overflow subprocess tag info page.

I tried the subprocess.run method. It works fine. It loads the model and as a result I can chat. But I need to send input to it and get output. How can I do this programmatically?

subprocess.run(..., input="your input here\n")

Going forward, probably explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish and where you are stuck.

Can I interactively send it questions and get their output using the subprocess.run method? As far as I know, this cannot be done with subprocess.run.

Nope, then you need bare  Popen

If you are not actually interacting with the process, this answer is still what I would tell you. Perhaps you can show us in the question how you are attempting to interact with it after opening it?
